# Configuring a static IP, gateway etc with vagrant and puppet

Tags: networking, puppet, vagrant

I'm using **http://forge.puppetlabs.com/razorsedge/network** but I can't configure it properly.

this is my puppetfile.pp

```
class network {
    static { "eth1":
        ipaddress  => "1.2.3.248",
        netmask    => "255.255.255.128",
        ensure     => "up",
    }
}

node default {
    include eth1
}
```

But won't work!

The doc says

```
network::if::static { "eth0":
  ipaddress  => "1.2.3.248",
  netmask    => "255.255.255.128",
  ensure     => "up",
}
```

may someone point me how to trnslate this :: in a puppet file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked around with this Vagrantfile

I setup two cards (the default one and a second public one) the first with my usual conf and the second with a custom static IP

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "precise32"

  config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 256]
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype1", "virtio"] # the main card (used for ssh and internal networking between host and guest)
    v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--nictype2", "virtio"] # a second card
    v.gui = true # for debug
  end


  config.vm.network :bridged, :bridge => "en0: Wi-Fi (Airport)", :adapter => 1 # the main card configuration
  config.vm.network :private_network, :ip => "192.168.2.100", :nictype => 'virtio', :adapter => 2 # the secondary card configuration with a static IP
end
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how this solved the problem please.

Comment: You're right. This won't solve, it's a workaroud. Edited

Comment: What I meant was can you explain a little what it does / why it helps, the bare link doesn't really do that.